# using parquet files statistics without reading the files

Tags: python, parquet, dask, pyarrow, fastparquet

To my understanding parquet files have min/max statistics for columns.
my question is how to read those stats using python without reading the entire file?

If it helps, I also have `_common_metadata` and `_metadata` files.

---

my specific problem is getting the max date for each stock exchange partition in this file system (each year partition contains multiple parquet files that have date column) :

```
C:.
│   _common_metadata
│   _metadata
├───source=NASDAQ
│   ├───year=2017
│   └───year=2018
├───source=London_Stock_Exchange
│   ├───year=2014
│   ├───year=2015
├───source=Japan_Exchange_Group
│   ├───year=2017
│   └───year=2018
└───source=Euronext
    ├───year=2017
    └───year=2018
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extract them on a per-RowGroup basis in `pyarrow`:

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

pq_file = pq.ParquetFile(…)
# Get metadata for the i-th RowGroup
rg_meta = pq_file.metadata.row_group(i)
# Get the "max" statistic for the k-th column
max_of_col = rq_meta.column(col).statistics.max
```

Comment: the `...` in `pq.ParquetFile(…)` is path to a file or a directory ?
if it's a file, what do you mean by  "i-th RowGroup" ?
I thought that RowGroup is per file

Comment: No, file can have a arbitrary number of RowGroups. This command is just for a single file. For multiple files, use a `ParquetDataset` and then iterate over all its `ParquetDatasetPiece`s.

Comment: so if want the max date i should `max` of all the maxes of each file?

Comment: Yes, that will give you the global maximum.

Comment: How to get the date from the int returned by rg.statistics.max

Answer (score 0):

after some additional searching i found this [`sorted_partitioned_columns`](https://www.pydoc.io/pypi/fastparquet-0.0.6/autoapi/api/index.html#api.api.sorted_partitioned_columns) in the `fastparquet` module.

it gives the mins and maxes of each file!

example:

```
>>> import fastparquet
>>> fastparquet.api.sorted_partitioned_columns(pf)
{'id': {'min': [1, 5, 10], 'max': [4, 9, 20]}}
```